# I would like to remove the white square border behind the ClipOval

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ClipOVal. Currently, I would like to remove the white square boarder behind the ClipOval.

[image]

```
              Card(fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  flex: 5,child:
                                ClipOval(
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: CONSTANTS.server +
                                        "/mytutor/mobile/assets/products/" +
                                        widget.user.userId.toString() +
                                        '.jpg',
                                        width:350,
                                        height:350,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                )),
                              ],
                            )),
```

Comment: Try to remove the Flexible widget.

Comment: Hmmm, it is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove card and add Container and add `color: Colors.transparent` or add the following to the card

```
color: Colors.transparent,
elevation: 0
```

The color is from the card thats above thr Column